# Loading lines of JSON from Amzon S3 to DyanmoDB

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have some output from my apache-spark (PySpark) code that looks like this (very simple JSON objects on per line):

```
{'id': 1, 'value1': 'blah', 'value2': 1, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
{'id': 2, 'value1': 'yada', 'value2': 1, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
{'id': 3, 'value1': 'blah', 'value2': 2, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
{'id': 4, 'value1': 'yada', 'value2': 2, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
{'id': 5, 'value1': 'blah', 'value2': 3, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
{'id': 6, 'value1': 'yada', 'value2': 4, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
```

I want to write them to a DynamoDB table as documents. I don't want to convert this to the Map format (if I can avoid it). Any ideas on how to pull this off? So little documentation on the formatting issue.

There is some new DocumentClient() thing, but I can't use it from CLI. For example, feeding one of the above lines as an item to the 'put-item' aws cli command gives error:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name mytable --item file://item.txt

Parameter validation failed:
Invalid type for parameter Item.......
```

Answer (score 0):

A JSON string, such as the following, can't be `put-item`ed directly in DynamoDB:

```
{'id': 1, 'value1': 'blah', 'value2': 1, 'value3': '2016-07-19 19:35:13'}
```

It needs to have a format like:

```
{"id": {"N": 1}, "value1": {"S": "blah"}, "value2": {"N": 1}, "value3": {"S": "2016-07-19 19:35:13"}}
```

That is because, from the former, DynamoDB doesn't have a way to know the data types of `id`, `value1` etc.

As I see it, you have two options:

- Transform your data, from the former to latter, by using some utility. For example, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).
- Use [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/).

Comment: Thank you. I am hoping to avoid re-casting data. But, it won't be end of world if I have to. When I use AWS Data Pipeline, it does not seem to handle this transformation itself. Is it expected to?

Comment: It should- I'd suggest you dig through its documentation; after accepting my answer that is!